# Which value for topmost-intro-cont, to align variable names in c-mode?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode, c-mode

In c-mode, how to align following code so, that the second variable name's starting character (`A`) is aligned below the first variable name's starting character (`V`)?

```
static unsigned int V_name_1,
                    A_name_2;
```

`c-show-syntactic-information` shows, that that indentation can be justified with `topmost-intro-cont`.
(I am unable to find a setting to achieve the wanted indentation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no valid function or value to set the indentation offset.
So I came up with a new function which needs to be assigned to `topmost-intro-cont`. Use `M-: c-set-offset` to do it temporarily in a buffer with c-mode.

Here is the function:

```
(defun c-lineup-topmost-intro-cont-symbol (elem)
    "calculate offset to previous declared symbol or
function name to align variable names on different lines."
    (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (c-beginning-of-statement-1)
        (when (search-forward-regexp  "[,(\[]" (line-end-position) t)
            (progn
                (search-backward-regexp "=" (line-beginning-position) t)
                (search-backward-regexp "\\<" (line-beginning-position) t)))
        (current-column)))
```

Short explanation: go to beginning of this statement, and search for `,` on current line. If it is not found return column of current indentation, else search backward for'=' and then for beginning of word and return column of beginning of this first symbol name.

Set this function with:

```
(add-to-list 'c-style-alist '( ;; your own stuff here
                              (c-offsets-alist . ( ;; your own stuff here
                                                  (topmost-intro-cont . (c-lineup-topmost-intro-cont-symbol))))))
```

Test case:

```
unsigned int foo = 5,
         blah;

unsigned int foo,
         blah;

unsigned int foo[],
         blah;

unsigned int foo[]={1,2},
         blah;


unsigned int foo= 5,
         blah;

unsigned int foo =5,
         blah;


unsigned int foo[] ={1,2},
         blah;

unsigned int foo[]= {1,2},
         blah;


unsigned int foo[]  = {1,2},
         blah;


unsigned int foo   = 1,
         blah;

unsigned int    foo,
        blah;

unsigned int    foo   = 1,
        blah;
```